# Data binding for template with on push detection strategy

Tags: templates, angular

I got two components: list and item and using `<template>` to set item renderer for the list:

```
        <chat-message-list [messages]="messages | async">
            <template>
                <chat-message [isTimestampVisible]="isTimestampVisible | async"></chat-message>
            </template>
        </chat-message-list>
```

And both list and message is using on push detection strategy (`ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`).

Before I used `<template>` to set item renderer `isTimestampVisible` property was properly bind. When I used `<template>` `isTimestampVisible` property is no longer refresh after change. I don't want to use default detection strategy because i got immutable model using React.

It's working properly when I pass `Observable` to `<chat-message>` instead of boolean value, but `<chat-message>` is my "dumb" component so it should not receive Observable - just pure value.

http://plnkr.co/edit/4qUDeOBoMmUsuRsBx2w9?p=preview

If you change `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` to `ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default` in `message-list.ts` binding is working.

Comment: Does it work when you change the components to default `ChangeDetectionStrategy`?

Comment: Yes, but without template it's working even with `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`. Without template data is passed through list: MyComponent->MessageList->Message

Comment: I guess this needs a Plunker to reproduce and debug.

Comment: I've added a plunker example. http://plnkr.co/edit/4qUDeOBoMmUsuRsBx2w9?p=preview

If you change `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` to `ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default` in `message-list.ts` binding is working.

And also if you remove template and use `message` component in `message-list` template its working with `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`

Answer (score 0):

With `OnPush` the component only runs change detection if you invoke it or when an input changes.

I just added an input to `<message-list>` and passed `isTimestampVisible` to make it update every time `isTimestampVisible` changes.

[**Plunker example**](http://plnkr.co/edit/aMeosgjC9gunDaUe0pZR?p=preview)

Comment: Yes but I want to pass my data directly to message component. Your implementation looks like workaround. If I want to pass my data through list component I could do this without templates.

Comment: It's not about passing the data, it's about notifying the list that it needs to update.

Comment: Ok I understand, I was thinking that if I pass data directly to message it will be updated.

Comment: You can pass any value to `[update]` (it just needs to be different than the previous one). With `OnPush` change detection is run when inputs change. You can invoke change detection by any other means `cdRef.detectChanges()` ... but it needs to be invoked. The simplest way was to pass `isTimestampVisible`, because it updates always when the component needs to be updated ;-)

Comment: Sure, but it still looks as a workaround for me and it's not easy to read code like this.

Comment: So, you want to use `OnPush` to only run change detection when pushed but you don't want to push ;-)

Comment: But I'm pushing data directly to message. Seems that if parent has also onPush detection I got to notify it.

Comment: I found another way. If you pass the observable directly and subscribe (use | async) in `Message` then message gets updated by `async`. I updated my Plunker.

Comment: I've wrote this solution in my first post.